# readline: difference between vi, vi-move, vi-command, vi-insert keymaps

Tags: readline

The readline(3) manpage lists these four (vi, vi-move, vi-command, vi-insert) as possible options for the `keymap` setting. I have tried setting these different options and they seem to have no effect beyond what `set editing-mode vi` does.

Probably the most succinct way to answer this question is to give an example of how changing `keymap` makes a difference.

Quote from the manpage:

```
keymap (emacs)
          Set the current readline keymap.  The set of legal keymap  names
          is  emacs,  emacs-standard, emacs-meta, emacs-ctlx, vi, vi-move,
          vi-command, and vi-insert.   vi  is  equivalent  to  vi-command;
          <<snip>>
```

Comment: Does anyone know what vi-move is?

Comment: It's another name for `vi-command` or `vi`... see my answer for proof :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the different keymaps inside vi mode. For example, my `.inputrc` sets `keymap` to bind keys in different modes. Excerpt:

```
# insert mode bindings
set keymap vi-insert
"\C-p": previous-history
"\C-n": next-history

# command mode bindings
set keymap vi-command
"|": beginning-of-line
"_": vi-first-print
```

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR**

If you want the gist, skip to the heading `editing-mode vi` (the last one).

But wait! There's a fair bit of background info that may be needed though: eg, the difference between an `editing-mode` and a `keymap`.

Particularly useful is the concept of a hybrid `emacs` keymap for inserting text and while still easily getting to `vi-command` for making changes.

**What is the difference between an `editing-mode` and a `keymap`?**

There are *only* two `editing-mode`s: `emacs` (the default) and `vi`.

The [GNU Readline Library documentation](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html) says:

> ```
> editing-mode
>     The editing-mode variable controls which default set of key bindings is
>     used. By default, Readline starts up in Emacs editing mode, where the
>     keystrokes are most similar to Emacs. This variable can be set to either
>     `emacs' or `vi'.
> ```

Note the difference between `editing-mode` and `keymap`: In `editing-mode vi` the two (yes there's only two, read on) keymaps are swapped in and out to emulate the different modes of the `vi` editor. *ALL* the `emacs` ones operate at the same time in `editing-mode emacs` (explained later).

So what does `editing-mode` actually do? It just sets the active keymap upon shell startup to either `emacs` or `vi-insert`.

**What are the unique keymaps?**

> ```
> Acceptable keymap names are emacs, emacs-standard, emacs-meta, emacs-ctlx,
> vi, vi-move, vi-command, and vi-insert.
>
> vi is equivalent to vi-command; emacs is equivalent to emacs-standard.
> ```

While not documented, `vi`/`vi-command` and `vi-move` keymaps are also equivalent:

```
+ravi@boxy:~$ diff <(bind -pm vi) <(bind -pm vi-move)
+ravi@boxy:~$
```

This leaves us with: `emacs`, `emacs-meta`, `emacs-ctlx`, `vi`, and `vi-insert` as unique keymaps to explain. Differentiating the keymaps is probably best done by inspecting them...

**What are the keymaps default bindings?**

To view the default keybindings for (example) emacs (the default), use:

```
INPUTRC=~/dev/null bash -c 'bind -pm emacs' | grep -v '^#
```

You can replace `emacs` with any other keymap name in the example above.

There are many lines saying `self-insert` or `do-lowercase-version` which aren't very useful, so to remove them:

```
INPUTRC=~/dev/null bash -c 'bind -pm emacs' | grep -vE '^#|: (do-lowercase-version|self-insert)$' | sort
```

**What is the difference between the various `emacs` keymaps?**

TL;DR: They are different views on a single set of mappings applied to `editing-mode emacs`.

If you the output of the second command into the files called `emacs-standard`, `emacs-meta`, `emacs-ctlx`, `vi-command`, and `vi-insert` for their corresponding `keymap`s, you can find out that:

There are NO commands mapped in `emacs-meta` and `emacs-ctlx` which don't also appear in `emacs-standard`:

```
$ comm -13 <(sed -r 's/.*: (\S+)/\1/' emacs-standard|sort) <(sed -r 's/.*: (\S+)/\1/' emacs-ctlx|sort)
$ comm -13 <(sed -r 's/.*: (\S+)/\1/' emacs-standard|sort) <(sed -r 's/.*: (\S+)/\1/' emacs-meta|sort)
$
```

So `emacs`/`emacs-standard` is a behaviourally functional superset of both `emacs-ctlx` and `emacs-meta` This means that:

```
keymap emacs
"\eg": glob-expand-word
"\C-x\C-r": re-read-init-file
```

Is functionally equivalent to:

```
keymap emacs-meta
"g": glob-expand-word

keymap emacs-ctlx
"\C-r": re-read-init-file
```

You might argue that the second form is easier to read.

**Inserting text: `emacs` vs `vi-insert`**

There are 28 commands in `emacs-standard` not in `vi-insert`

```
+ravi@boxy:~/lib/readline$ comm -12 vi-insert emacs-standard |wc -l
28
+ravi@boxy:~/lib/readline$
```

`emacs`/`emacs-standard` is basically a superset of `vi-insert`. So for typing text, it's best to use the `emacs-standard` keymap over `vi-insert` as long as you can [easily switch between `emacs` and `vi-command`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303637/readline-how-do-i-change-from-emacs-to-vi-command-with-a-binding).

The only additional bindings in `vi-insert` not in `emacs-standard` are:

```
+ravi@boxy:~/lib/readline$ comm -23 vi-insert emacs-standard 
"\C-d": vi-eof-maybe
"\C-n": menu-complete
"\C-p": menu-complete-backward
"\e": vi-movement-mode
```

The first 3 of these four conflict with `emacs` bindings:

```
"\C-d": delete-char
"\C-n": next-history
"\C-p": previous-history
```

which I resolved as follows:

```
set keymap emacs
"\e": "kj" # see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303631/how-can-i-setup-a-hybrid-readline-with-emacs-insert-mode-and-vi-command-mode
"\C-d": delete-char # eof-maybe: ^D does nothing if there is text on the line
"\C-n": menu-complete
"\C-p": menu-complete-backward
"\C-y": previous-history # historY
"\e\C-y": previous-history
```

### **`editing-mode vi`**

As we saw above, `vi`, `vi-command` and `vi-move` are *one and the same* keymap:

```
+ravi@boxy:~$ diff <(bind -pm vi) <(bind -pm vi-move)
+ravi@boxy:~$
```

Note that's a total of just *two* distinct maps which are associated by default with `editing-mode vi`.

When in `editing-mode vi`, the `keymap`s in use are `vi`/`vi-command`/`vi-move` and `vi-insert` (the starting keymap). Only one of these two maps is active at a time.

`editing-mode vi` does nothing more than set a default keymap when the shell starts, labelled `vi-insert`. Again, tthere is only one keymap active at a time. This `vi-insert` keymap maps most keys to `self-insert` so when you press the plastic button on your keyboard, the symbol printed on it appears on your screen.

The `vi-insert` keymap allows itself to be swapped to the text-manipulating keymap called `vi-command`/`vi`/`vi-move` by using `vi-movement-mode` command, bound to the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key by default in the `vi-insert` keymap.

Actually, even the `emacs` keymap can set the `vi`-like text manipulation keymap active by using the `vi-movement-mode` command, as in the hybrid solution mentioned above.

**Or in easier language...**

By default, press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to change to the `vi-command` keymap when the `vi-insert` keymap is active.

The `vi-command` keymap uses standard, single keypresses like <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>b</kbd> and <kbd>c</kbd> to move and interact with text, just like the `vi` editor's default or command mode. There are generally no <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> combinations. You can't insert text in this mode; the letter keys are mapped to editing/moving commands. For typing text, you switch to the `vi-insert` keymap (example: press <kbd>i</kbd> for "Insert").

Entering text is done using the the `vi-insert` keymap, which is active when the shell starts if you have `editing-mode vi` in your `.inputrc` file. Swap to the `vi-insert` keymap by pressing <kbd>i</kbd> for "insert" while in `vi-command` (or in numerous other ways for those initiated into `vi`).

Unless you know the `vi` editor, you'll probably find `vi-command` keys very hard to use at first, but if you get good at it, you can edit text like a long-bearded wizard.