# Why do `bind` and `.inputrc` behave differently?

Tags: bash, terminal, key-binding, readline, inputrc

I'm trying to do the right thing and put my key bindings into `~/.inputrc`.

However, it turns out that I have to change

```
bind '"\e\C-j":"\e[1~quiet \e[4~\n"'
```

into

```
"\e\C-j": "\eOHquiet \eOF\n"
```

Now `\eOH` (nav-block-pos1 bound to `beginning-of-line`) and `\eOF` (nav-block-end bound to `end-of-line`) are themselves bindings in my configuration which I possibly cannot always rely on.

So the main question is why does binding to num-block-pos1 (`\e[1~`) and num-block-end (`\e[4~`) work with `bind` but not in my `~/.inputrc`?

---

**Edit:**

The whole thing is getting even more complicated, now that I realized that `\e\C-j` only works for Gnome Terminial (or probably xterm as well, who knows...).

For my TTY it has to be

```
"\e\C-m": "\e[1~_quiet \e[4~\n"
```

So is it that various VTs have different implementations of how to interpret keys or what?

Comment: This is documented in the _GNU Readline User Interface_ manual, section 1.3.

The `keymap` option is used to set what kind of key representation is used in key bindings definitions. 

Relevant information: 
http://superuser.com/questions/286781/readline-difference-between-vi-vi-move-vi-command-vi-insert-keymaps 
http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html#SEC9 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Readline

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин How exactly is this relevant to the difference in behavior between using `bind` and using `inputrc` for the actual binding. Should they not use the same settings?

Answer (score 2):

Your terminal emulator can operate in one of two modes: application mode, and cursor mode (see http://homes.mpimf-heidelberg.mpg.de/%7Erohm/computing/mpimf/notes/terminal.html). It depends on what mode your particular application runs in that determines what escape sequence you need to send.