# What does "vi-move" keymap in Bash's vi mode actually do?

Tags: bash, vi, readline

The keymap section in the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-keymap) says that one of the acceptable options is "vi-move".  There doesn't seem to be any description for what this corresponds to.  I'm well acquainted with "vi-command" and "vi-insert", but can't seem to find anything regarding "vi-move".

I had hoped that [this](https://superuser.com/questions/286781/readline-difference-between-vi-vi-move-vi-command-vi-insert-keymaps) question would shed some light on things, but no such luck.

Answer (score 1):

`diff <(bind -p -m vi-move) <(bind -p -m vi-command)` shows no difference, so I guess they are just synonyms. Nevertheless, the readline documentation only states that vi and vi-command are equivalent and, despite it mentions vi-mode in the same paragraph, it fails to assert the equivalence between the three modes. So, I have asked Chet Ramey and his authoritative answer was "yes [the three are the same]".

Answer (score 0):

Searching through the bash manual locally, the string "vi-move" shows up in the VI Mode bindings section:

```
VI Mode bindings
         VI Insert Mode functions

         "C-D"  vi-eof-maybe
         ... <snip>
         "C-["  vi-movement-mode
         ...
```

In `vim` doing `:help ^[` shows this:

```
                                            i_CTRL-[ i_<Esc>                                                                                              
<Esc> or CTRL-[ End insert or Replace mode, go back to Normal mode.  Finish
            abbreviation. 
            Note: If your <Esc> key is hard to hit on your keyboard, train
            yourself to use CTRL-[.
```

This is just the transition key to go from Insert mode to Normal mode, so I think `vi-move` is basically "Normal" mode in vim.  I'm not sure how that maps to something useful in Bash, though.  My `keymap` shows either `vi` or `vi-insert` depending on whether I invoke bash -V by typing it or by hitting `Esc k CR` to replay from history.

Answer (score 0):

`vi-move`, `vi-command` and `vi` are synonyms for *one and the same* keymap (as proven by @memeplex), and is the one set active by the `vi-movement-mode` command.

The `vi-insert` keymap is set active by the `editing-mode vi` command, or `set -o vi`.

Note that in `bash` v4.3.11(1), executing the `vi-movement-mode` command when the `emacs` keymap is active doesn't change the prompt if `show-mode-in-prompt` is `on`, but changing to `vi-editing-mode` does. 
The work-around is [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303637/readline-how-do-i-change-keymaps-from-emacs-to-vi-command-with-a-binding/303643#303643).