# Enable gnome-terminal hotkeys depending on the vi mode in the terminal

Tags: bash, vi, gnome-terminal

I have recently discovered that it is possible to enable vim bindings in the `gnome-terminal` with:

`set -o vi`

Now I would like to know whether it is possible to also enable hotkeys for the terminal depending on the mode (`NORMAL`, `INSERT`) I am currently in.

E.g. I would like to set `next tab` in the terminal to `shift+k` when I am in `NORMAL` mode. When I am in `INSERT` mode `K` should be written.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [readline: difference between vi, vi-move, vi-command, vi-insert keymaps](https://superuser.com/questions/286781/readline-difference-between-vi-vi-move-vi-command-vi-insert-keymaps)

Comment: That definitely goes into the right direction. The problem I see is that those are just macros which write to the terminal. They are not recognized as keystrokes by the terminal, hence I cant bind a macro to a terminal shortcut (just tried). I can't find a terminal command to switch between tabs, only new tab / window is possible afaik.

Comment: But I should be able to call other script from there. I found `xdotool` which can inject keystrokes into the system as it seems, but it's pretty slow.

Comment: I thought it's about "bash hotkeys depending on the mode". Making Bash spawn a new tab in the terminal emulator it uses is a *separate* issue, unless your terminal emulator integrates itself with Bash in some clever way (hypothetical situation; and you did not tell us what terminal emulator you're using). You said `only new tab / window is possible afaik`. What do you mean?

Comment: I am sorry I am using the `gnome-terminal` on ubuntu20.04. I edited the question. I used bash as a synonym for the terminal emulator, sry for the confusion.

Comment: You did add `gnome-terminal` to the question title but did not explain it in the question body. I first had to read the comments to get what you are _actually_ trying to achieve here, so you should expand on this in your question a bit more.
I agree with @KamilMaciorowski: `bash` and its `vi mode` are not really connected to the _terminal emulator_ i.e. `gnome-terminal`, so you are looking for some kind of clever integration between these two here.